# Convert self.window.rootViewController = colorTouchVC to message sending form?

Tags: objective-c

I'm new to Objective-C, so far to my understanding, the **dot form** and **message sending** form can be converted vice versa. So How to convert the following expression to **message sending form**

```
self.window.rootViewController = colorTouchVC;
```

My version:

```
 [self setWindow:[self setRootViewController: colorTouchVC]];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[self window] setRootViewController:colorTouchVC];
```

`window` is a property in this particular case, not a method.

Comment: I think @window property generate getter method **window** and setter method **setWindow** automatically, am I correct on this point?

Comment: I figure it out myself, it's a getter instead of setter, so **window&& should be used, cheers man

Answer (score 1):

try With

```
[[self window]setRootViewController:colorTouchVC];
```